# GRUB: guessing what is my operating system number to boot

Tags: grub2

In the past, using `grub-reboot` for **booting into another operating system** was easy when concerning to guess the **number of the option** in the GRUB's list, for example:

```
luis@VirtuKali:~$ more /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep menuentry --color
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.14-kali1-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.14-kali1-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
```

... so I know that option 0 (the first) boots into normal Kali Linux, and option 1 (the second) boots into recovery mode, and I can happily do:

```
# grub-reboot 1
```

But in **modern versions of GRUB**, and when having **multiple operating systems**, things are not so easy.
For example, look at this mess:

```
luis@balanceador:~$ more /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep menuentry --color
if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
  menuentry_id_option=""
export menuentry_id_option
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-d795f672-83d4-451e-bea4-0db5c70512b8' {
submenu 'Opciones avanzadas para Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-d795f672-83d4-451e-bea4-0db5c70512b8' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, con Linux 3.13.0-39-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-39-generic-advanced-d795f672-83d4-451e-bea4-0db5c70512b8' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-39-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-39-generic-recovery-d795f672-83d4-451e-bea4-0db5c70512b8' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, con Linux 3.13.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-advanced-d795f672-83d4-451e-bea4-0db5c70512b8' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-recovery-d795f672-83d4-451e-bea4-0db5c70512b8' {
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
menuentry 'Microsoft Windows XP Professional (en /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-1D8E45A744914BEC' {
menuentry 'Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (14.04) (en /dev/sda6)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-45d94105-0a37-49fb-8b14-e201b807d493' {
submenu 'Opciones avanzadas para Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (14.04) (en /dev/sda6)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-45d94105-0a37-49fb-8b14-e201b807d493' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu (en /dev/sda6)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic--45d94105-0a37-49fb-8b14-e201b807d493' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, con Linux 3.13.0-39-generic (en /dev/sda6)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic--45d94105-0a37-49fb-8b14-e201b807d493' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-39-generic (recovery mode) (en /dev/sda6)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic-root=UUID=45d94105-0a37-49fb-8b14-e201b807d493 ro recovery nomodeset-45d94105-0a37-49fb-8b14-e201b807d493' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (14.04) (en /dev/sda7) (en /dev/sda6)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic--45d94105-0a37-49fb-8b14-e201b807d493' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu (en /dev/sda7) (en /dev/sda6)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic--45d94105-0a37-49fb-8b14-e201b807d493' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, con Linux 3.13.0-39-generic (en /dev/sda7) (en /dev/sda6)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic--45d94105-0a37-49fb-8b14-e201b807d493' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-39-generic (recovery mode) (en /dev/sda7) (en /dev/sda6)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic-root=UUID=d795f672-83d4-451e-bea4-0db5c70512b8 ro recovery nomodeset-45d94105-0a37-49fb-8b14-e201b807d493' {
```

In the past, I simply **counted the number** of `menuentry` instances (starting from 0), but now the **correspondence is not the same** as I see in the GRUB menu when the computer boots up.
My only workaround for now is to type things like:

```
# grub-reboot "Microsoft Windows XP Professional (en /dev/sda1)"
```

Not a great problem, but it requires copy-paste. Numbers are easier and more scriptables.

Is there **any other trick**? Maybe my grep command must be updated?

Thanks.

Comment: Tried ignoring `menuentry` items in submenus (that is, each entire submenu counts as only one entry)?

Comment: Well, @muru, you seem to be right (I had not realized it until watching in a tagged code window :-) ). Each `menuentry` in submenus seems to have a `TAB` just before. Maybe we could grep it that way. And yes: each submenu is only one entry in the boot menu in the GRUB screen when booting.

Comment: You can also disable submenus - it may make the actual menu much more uglier, but could simplify your scripting.

Answer (score 1):

> Even when this proposed solution **works for the original question**
>   (corresponding to Kali Linux), some implementations (i.e: Ubuntu v14)
>   of `grub.cfg` may have no `TABs` at the beginning of the lines.
>   [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167021/57439) is a **more platform-independent** solution, that could (lets hope) work
>   for any GRUB installation.

This is the solution (I use it as an alias):

```
alias GRUB-ListMenuOptions='more /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep -e "^menuentry" -e "submenu" --color'
```

Entries named `menuentry` at the beginning of the line plus entries named `submenu`.

Tested working with GRUB 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.
Thanks, @muru, for the ideas.