# GRUB v2: Practical way to manage numerical entries in order to use with grub-reboot

Tags: grub

I use **GRUB v2** as my boot manager.
Whenever I want to **reboot to another** operating system (or menu entry, like `MemTest`), I use the command:

```
# grub-reboot n
```

where `n` is the number (starting on 0) of the **desired menu entry**.
For example:

[image: GRUB2 menu example]

so, if, in the above example, I want to reboot to `Squeeze Linux` I will enter:

```
# grub-reboot 4
```

But, when having multiple computers and/or operating systems, it is **hard to remember** the number of this entry, and I finally need to reboot to the menu to check for the number.

I know the **entries are stored** at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` on lines named `menuentry` or "submenu` but, as long as GRUB becomes more complex (and advanced, of course), this file is a bit awkward to read in order to count number of entries.

Is there a practical way to **know the number of all the entries** of the GRUB v2 boot menu?

Answer (score 2):

I use this **command line**, that is just a parsing of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, in order to **show numbered entries**, one per line:

```
sed ':again;$!N;$!b again; :b; s/{[^{}]*}//g; t b' /boot/grub/grub.cfg | cut -c -60 | grep -e "^menuentry" -e "submenu" | nl -v 0 | grep -e "menuentry" -e "submenu" --color
```

that results (not the same example as the graphic before, sorry):

[image: GRUB-ListMenu results example]

My preferred method is to add it as an **alias or function**. For example, as a function in `~/bashrc` :

```
# List entries numbers for grub-reboot:
function GRUB-ListMenu() {
        sed ':again;$!N;$!b again; :b; s/{[^{}]*}//g; t b' /boot/grub/grub.cfg | cut -c -60 | grep -e "^menuentry" -e "submenu" | nl -v 0 | grep -e "menuentry" -e "submenu" --color
}
```

**Explanation**:

- The `sed` command **removes all lines between curly brackets** (`{` and `}`), due they correspond to **drop-down submenus**.
- The `cut` command leaves only the first 60 characters, in order to make results **more readable** for the user.
- The `grep` command leaves only the lines corresponding to **real menu entries**: `menuentry` and `submenu`.
- The `nl` command **numerates** each line (starting from 0, of course).
- There is an addition `grep` command, not strictly needed, that simply adds **colors** to the results ;-) .

Advices about optimizations are welcome.
Tested working on GRUB v2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1 running on Ubuntu Desktop, Server, v12, v14, Kali and BackTrack. Feedbacks about behavior in another Linux are encouraged (I will add them to this post).